# How to place a large figure at the bottom in LaTeX?

Tags: floats, bottom

I have a large figure almost the dimensions of an A4 paper, which I want to include in my `LaTeX` as a figure in a separate page. Following is the code that I am using:

```
\newpage
\begin{figure}[b]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-2.0in}{0in}
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{figure.pdf}
    \caption{bla bli blu.}
    \label{parameters}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure}
```

The problem is, Latex is automatically cropping some of the upper part of the figure and placing it at somewhat centre of the page, even though I am using `[b]` to force it in the bottom of the page. This is how it looks like: [image: This is how it looks like:]

How can I solve it?

Comment: by default in the standard classes `[b]` only allows 30% of a page at most. You have not show an example but it is probably similar so `[b]` is preventing the float to be placed anywhere until flushed out by `\clearpage` when it will be vertically centred (again or not, depending on code not shown)

Comment: use `[p]` (or no option at all, not `[b]`)

Comment: If a float is placed on a page all by itself, LaTeX will try to place it in the middle of the page by default.